# How can i send and save credit card data from ecommerce website to desktop Quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

I was wondering how can I send customer credit card data from ecommerce website to Quickbooks. There are some concepts i am confused.

From my understanding, basically I can process credit card on my ecommerce website using "Merchant Service for Web Stores" API, and i found there is a "Payment wallet" function, is the connected to customer credit card info on desktop Quickbooks? What's the proper way to process credit card for my ecommerce site and at the meantime sending the customer credit card data into my desktop Quickbooks, saved there and for future use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ps: The ecommerce site is by PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering how can I send customer credit card data from ecommerce website to Quickbooks.

Are you **sure** you actually need the credit card data *in QuickBooks*? You should know that if doing this, you likely won't be [PCI compliant](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php) without jumping through *a lot* of hoops - and remember that storing credit card data on site is *incredibly* dangerous from a litigation/security/legal standpoint. You're setting yourself up to get sued when that data gets stolen.

> From my understanding, basically I can process credit card on my ecommerce website using "Merchant Service for Web Stores" API,

Yes.

> and i found there is a "Payment wallet" function,

Yes, and this is what you should be using. It securely stores the data *with Intuit* instead of with you, so that you are still PCI compliant and the card data is safe.

It allows you to push credit card data to Intuit, and they return a unique ID value to you which you can use to charge the credit card at any time in the future, without actually having to know the card number itself.

> is the connected to customer credit card info on desktop Quickbooks?

No, it's not.

> What's the proper way to process credit card for my ecommerce site and at the meantime sending the customer credit card data into my desktop Quickbooks, saved there and for future use?

You don't want to do this. There *is no proper way to do this*. It's a terrible, insecure practice. Don't do it.

*Instead,* charge the credit card via the QBMS API, and then *store the credit card in the payment wallet and store the payment wallet unique ID in your database*. You can then write a simple program that lives and uses that unique wallet ID to charge them again at any time.

Since you're using PHP, this is the best place to start (disclaimer: I'm the author of the below code):

- [open source QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php)

Specifically, you'll want to look at the QuickBooks Merchant Service examples:

- [PHP - charge credit cards with Intuit QuickBooks Merchant Services](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_merchant_service.php)
- [PHP - store credit card info securely with Intuit QuickBooks Merchant Services](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_merchant_service_wallet.php)

Before you can really utilize the code, you'll have to go through a very simple registration process with Intuit (register in DESKTOP mode for easiest implementation).

- [Quick-start for Intuit QuickBooks Merchant Services with PHP](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Merchant_Services#Getting_started_with_the_.27Desktop.27_communication_model)

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. I still have one point not understood. QBMS for Quickbooks can store the credit card associate with customer and use it to bill in future. On Quickbooks doc, it says the credit card info is actually stored on intuit server, not on Quickbooks local computer , which is actually similar to "Payment Wallet" and  is PCI compliant. So for those two, Are they in any way connected? Rather than using payment wallet to bill from the php application or online, the client wants to do it directly from Quickbooks. Hope I explained clearly. Many thanks

Comment: As far as I know, they are not connected in any way. Your client should be made aware that pushing any credit card data to QuickBooks is not secure, and not recommended. With that said, you should be able to push credit card data into QuickBooks via the QuickBooks API/Web Connector.

Comment: "You should be able to push credit card data into QuickBooks via the QuickBooks API/Web Connector", you mean only the transactions for recording purpose?

Comment: [http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/pages/inproducthelp/core/qb2k13/contentpackage/core/center_customer/info_qb_saves_cc_data.html] "If you recently started processing cards, QuickBooks helps you comply by handling this sensitive information for you. QuickBooks automatically saves credit card data online with your private account information at our protected data center, removing PCI-compliance headaches."

Comment: You should be able to push *the actual credit card data* to QuickBooks, in addition to the transaction. You shouldn't, but you can. The problem is that you're not only *storing* the data (one part of PCI compliance) you're also *transferring the data over the wire from your website to your desktop PC before it can be stored* AND you'll have to temporarily cache the credit card data before you can send it to QuickBooks.

Comment: 1. I am not going to store the real credit card data, as the link above says, "QuickBooks automatically saves credit card data online with your private account information at our protected data center, removing PCI-compliance headaches." 2. Transferring SSL encrypted data should be fine for PCI, since it's the method clients sending cc data to server and the application sending it to QBMS or authorize.net.  3. Can you tell me where i can find any documentation for "push credit card data into QuickBooks via the QuickBooks API/Web Connector". Thanks!

Comment: Quick-start: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

Comment: OSR: https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html  Look up CustomerAdd and look at the credit card fields. If you think the only thing you need to pass PCI is SSL, you're woefully mis-informed.